CDF of a linear combination of indepdendent discrete random variables
Let's suppose a collection of independently distributed random variables, and that they are discrete, and denoted by their probably mass function:
$$p_{X_i}(x) := P(X_i = x)$$
And let $Y=w_1X_1 + w_2X_2 + ... +w_kX_k$ be a convex combination of the $X_i$'s (i.e. $w_i \geq 0$ and $\sum_i w_i = 1$). To compute the c.d.f. of $Y$
$$P(Y \leq y) = \sum_{x_1=-\infty}^{\infty}p_{X_1}(x_1)\left(\sum_{x_2=-\infty}^{\infty} p_{X_2}(x_2) \dots \left(\sum_{x_k=-\infty}^{\frac{y-w_1x_1-w_2x_2-\dots-w_{k-1}x_{k-1}}{w_k}} p_{X_k}(x_k)\right)\right)$$
Computationally, for a given $y$, the naive method would be to form a $n_1 \times n_2 \dots \times n_k$ table (where $n_i$ is the number of non-zero-probability values of $X_i$), and add up the probabily masses under the hyper-plane $w_1x_1 + \dots + w_kx_k$. But that's of course exponentially-timed in $k$.  The formula above does not seem to help, as the inner most summation bounds depend on all the $x_i$'s and have to be enumerated.. Wonder if there are more efficient methods? Thanks!

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/499288/distribution-of-a-linear-combination-of-bernoulli-random-variables
This seems helpful.
